# No operations after closed connection, bypassing my check for a closed connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have code that loops through a queue of objects that describe information needing to be stored in a MySQL db. I recently changed the code a little to close connections in a `finally` block throughout the application so that we don't leak any when an exception occurs. It works great except:

Some users sometimes see the error `No operations allowed after resultset closed` - I know what the error means but I can't figure out how it could be closed.

The offending code:

```
    PreparedStatement s = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        if( !queue.isEmpty() ){

            conn = Prism.dbc();
            if(conn == null || conn.isClosed()){
                return;
            }
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            s = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT query goes here");
            int i = 0;
            while (!queue.isEmpty()){
                Handler a = queue.poll();
                if( a == null || a.isCanceled() ) continue;
                // .. value setting code here
                s.addBatch();
                if ((i + 1) % perBatch == 0) {
                    s.executeBatch(); // Execute every x items.
                }
                i++;
            }

            s.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // error logging code
    } finally {
        if(s != null) try { s.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
        if(conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
```

The error points to the `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` line. However, I don't see how the connection could be closed at this point because I'm explicitly checking for a closed/null connection just above it.

Comment: Are you able to connect to db using sql client and execute queries?

Comment: This happens to users and I can't really tell what the causes are to reproduce it - but those reporting it have never had this issue until I changed the application to use the `finally` blocks. I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with their db - because a reboot of our app resets the connection.

Comment: I doubt if finally has anything to do with it. It could be db driver issue [as driver used by different users might be different]. I would suggest to ask users to connect to db using SQL client, if that works then ensure that all users have same DB drivers installed.

Comment: Could you provide the whole stack trace?

Comment: Stack from the most recent user having this issue: http://pastebin.com/TE5vBNkq - link to source where error occurs (code as above) https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/actionlibs/ActionRecorder.java#L169

Comment: Can you provide details about DB driver being used?

Comment: Standard jdbc MySQL drivers, used by jdbc-pool, but we have several users reporting the issue and it only started with a recent version release. I highly doubt it's the driver.

Comment: Standard jdbc drivers can have different versions , see my answer below , it has the link. The fact that some users are able to run code smoothly indicates its not a code issue rather some dependency issue like driver which is different in different systems.

Comment: Or it means that not all of our users have updated yet, or have encountered the situation that causes this. All of our users have been fine and not having this error until they tried the latest version of our software.

Comment: Is your code used from multiple threads? Maybe your code isn't thread safe and connections are used on multiple threads; one closes it and the other attempts to use it?

Comment: Yes, but nothing should be closing the pool connection. Startup: we open pool connections. App starts a db purge thread that grabs a pool connection and when it's done we close the connection (returned to pool). App starts a thread that records data to db (where this error comes from). Grabs a conn/closes when done. Thread repeats every few seconds, checking queue. Main thread runs lookup code to read data when user needs it.

Comment: Nothing closes the connection. It is still open on the client side, but rejected on the server side because there was no communication for more than the configured `wait_timeout` interval. When setting autocommit to true, client tries to connect to the server and *boom* receives an error.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem I found in the stack trace is this:
`2013-03-31 13:21:11 [SEVERE] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,491,788 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 30,491,788 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.`

The connection you get when calling `Prism.dbc();` is actually one from a connection pool; and in that specific case, the pooled connection is *broken*. It says that there hasn't been a successful communication between the JDBC connection within the pool and the database for more than 8h. Maybe it's because of the mentioned `wait_timeout` defined at the database server or a firewall dropped the connection or anything; there can be a multitude of reasons why the connection broke.

You should follow the suggestions being made by the exception to solve this issue.

Comment: So here's the problem I run into - if I write code for my app to detect this error so that I can automatically close and reconnect database connections - it always happens as an exception. That means that a user actions will fail, we'll reconnect to the db, but then the user has to activate the query again. I need to find a way to re-establish connection with the DB before letting their query fail - the only way I can think of is use some sort of test query. Suggestions?

Comment: In your `Prism.initDbPool` method, you could set some additional config parameters for your pool, e.g. `setTestOnBorrow(true)` (which will cause the pool to run a validation query before providing a `Connection`). Be sure to set a validation query, too. Note that this comes with some kind of performance penalty, though, as executing the validation query obviously takes some time. For MySQL, `SELECT 1` should suffice. You should have a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html to get an understanding of what is possible.

Comment: In your case, you may better go with `testWhileIdle` and an appropriate value for `validationInterval` ... maybe try this one before you turn on `testOnBorrow`.

Comment: I'm one step ahead and just added this to dev builds of the app - but my concern is I'm unclear on what the pool does if the validation query doesn't work. The docs say it throws out the connection and tries to get another, but if the application has sat idling for hours, they may all be stale. Does the validation query system somehow force a new connection to the database? Or do I still have to detect for the "closed connection" exception and run the full reconnect code myself...

Comment: You should really read this: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html
The pool will always attempt to return a valid connection. When you use `testWhileIdle`, you do not interact with the pool anyway, it's running in the background. If you use `testOnBorrow` and the pool fetches a broken connection, it will try to give you another one. If the second one would be broken also - well, I guess you need to have a look at the code. But anyhow, you're better off than now. Maybe it's enough for you to set a `maxAge` value of 4h or so. You can go either way, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely reason for this issue is incompatibility between JDK version and DB driver being used.

Check this link : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j , it provides various versions of DB driver.

EDIT:

Se this link for jdk and driver mapping : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-versions-java.html .

EDIT:

The reason i say this is the most likely reason is from experience of working with DB. I don't think its a code issue as it is working for some people. Using incompatible drivers can lead to strange issues like the one you are facing.
I have faced such issues with Oracle DB where i was able to execute all the queries except Merge query which resulted in closed connection and issue was due to incompatible driver.

So i say this from my experience.

Also i do feel even if this not the exact cause of issue [its a most likely cause of issue] if user can post the driver version and jdk version we can definately rule this out, this post can certainly help people, so i dont see reason for downvote.

Comment: I guess the error would occur much more often in that case, if not always.

Comment: *Why* is that the most likely reason?

Comment: @Skirsch: Why? it depends on your driver, so if just one user has wrong driver then it will happen for only one user.

Comment: I would request to either remove downvote or tell reason for downvote

Comment: @Lokesh: I was first under the impression that this is a client-server-app, where there's only one driver involved; that is the one of the server. But as the clients seem to connect to the database directly, driver issues may be relevant, true. But a) I assume the software ships with the driver - BotskoNet: would you please confirm/deny? and b) I still would expect the troubles to be more consistent and the users with faulty drivers should run into trouble more often than not.
And I didn't downvote :O